# Extract two string from a string with a space

Tags: c, string, substring

let's suppose

```
char nickAndPwd[] = "John 1234";
```

i want to get `nick ="John"` and `password = "1234"`.How can I do it?

This is what I did but it seems not to work properly

```
int main() {  

  char nicknameAndPwd[] = "Alessandro 12345678901";
  char nick[10];
  char pwd[11];

  int nickLength = 10;
  int pwdLength = 11;

  memcpy( nick, &nicknameAndPwd[0], nickLength);
  nick[nickLength] = '\0';

  memcpy(pwd, &nicknameAndPwd[nickLength+1], pwdLength);
  pwd[pwdLength] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", nick);
  printf("%s\n", pwd);

  return 0;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `nick[nickLength] = '\0'` will write *out of bounds!* The size of an array is not the top index, it's the number of elements. So when you define `nick` as an array of `10` elements, that means the valid indexes are `0` to `9` (inclusive).

Comment: After you fix the error as explained above you could do a memset( nick, 0, sizeof( nick )) to null it out.  Alternatively if you don't want to use memcpy, you can use the "c" function strtok(), it's in string.h

Comment: One doesn't even need to make a copy, just assign a pointer with `strtok` or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know *exactly* the length of the name and the password,
you should probably try something like this.

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <stdio.h>

void
test_function(const char *nicknameAndPwd)
{
  printf("testing with <%s>\n", nicknameAndPwd);
  char nick[11]; // assume no more than 10 useful chars
  char pwd[12]; // assume no more than 11 useful chars
  if(sscanf(nicknameAndPwd, "%10s %11s", nick, pwd)==2)
  {
    nick[10]='\0'; // ensure string termination if input was too long
    pwd[11]='\0'; // ensure string termination if input was too long
    printf("  nick <%s>\n", nick);
    printf("  pwd <%s>\n", pwd);
  }
}

int
main(void)
{
  test_function("Alessandro 12345678901");
  test_function("Shorter 1234567");
  test_function("NowItIsLonger 1234567");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code into:

```
  nick[nickLength-1] = '\0';
  pwd[pwdLength-1] = '\0';
```

Both `nick` and `pwd` are allocated with the range of `[0,size-1]`.

A more general way to split the string with whitespace could be:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {  

  char nicknameAndPwd[50];
  char *p;
  fgets(nicknameAndPwd,50,stdin);
  if (p=strchr(nicknameAndPwd,'\n')) *p='\0';
  p = strchr(nicknameAndPwd,' ');
  char nick[25];
  char *pswd;
  strncpy(nick,nicknameAndPwd,p-nicknameAndPwd);
  pswd = nicknameAndPwd+(p-nicknameAndPwd)+1;
  puts(nick);
  puts(pswd);
}
```